# Context returning undefined - useContext

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-context

I'm trying to set up `useContext` in the simplest way possible, but it keeps returning `undefined`.

I've checked it several times but still can't decipher what I'm missing.

`Context.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export const Context = React.createContext();

export function Provider(props) {

    const sayHi = () => {
        console.log('hi')
    }

    const value = {
        actions: {
            sayHi
        }
    }

    return(
        <Context.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </Context.Provider>
    );
}
```

Consumer component (`Transfer.js`):

```js
import React, { useContext } from 'react';
import { Context } from '../Context';

function Transfer() {
    const value = useContext(Context);
    console.log(value); // ------> returns undefined
    console.log(Context); // ----> it is defined

    return (
        <div className="send">
            // some HTML
        </div>
    );
}


export default Transfer;
```

`Folder structure`:

```
src
└───components
│   └─── Transfer.js
│  
└───App.js
└───App.scss
└───Context.js
    ...
```

Comment: Have you added 'Provider' to your App.js (or some root component)

Comment: Awesome! That was what I was missing. Thanks @Sumith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi @cdgmachado : The issue is due to an empty value when you're creating context value instead use this :
export const Context = React.createContext(null)
This where i've read about it .
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/how-to-use-react-context-effectively .
You can look my codesandbox also :
https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-bash-z1cnq?file=/src/Context.js:28-76

From the blog : This a capture of the part talking about :

[image]

Hope that it'll solve it

Answer (score 4):

Answer: Missing `Provider` on root component